# How to create array dynamically in php/magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have tried the following code

```
<?php

foreach ($_wishlistitemCollection as $_wishlistitem):
    $_product  = $_wishlistitem->getProduct();
    $imgpath   = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image');
    $physpaths = array($imgpath);
endforeach;
?>
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $physpaths[$i];
}
?>
```

There's no error but the problem is that it doesn't display all elements in array `$physpaths`.

Please help me how to ensure that `$physpaths` contains all the elements or Simply point out where I have committed mistake.

Comment: Are you using `echo` to verify the contents of `$physpaths`?

Comment: Yes exactly I am using echo to verify its contents

Comment: Check out my answer below. `var_dump()` is much better to verify the contents of an array (or object).

Comment: Thanks everybody for supporting me......

Comment: Instead of using var_dump, you may be happier with what Zend_Debug returns! Please try this for outputting $physpaths once it has been populated: Zend_Debug::dump($physpaths); - you will see, with bigger objects that the way Zend_Debug formats the info is sooooo easier to read and thus make debugging sooooo "pleasing"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So close ;)

```
<?php
$physpaths = array();
foreach ($_wishlistitemCollection as $_wishlistitem):
    $_product  = $_wishlistitem->getProduct();
    $imgpath   = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image');
    $physpaths[] = $imgpath;
endforeach;
?>
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $physpaths[$i];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the above solution but it's repeating same path multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

In order to append a value to an array at a new index, you should either use `array_push()` or `[]`:

```
<?php
foreach(...) :
    .
    .
    .
    // use this
    $physpaths[] = $imgpath;
    // or this
    array_push($physpaths, $imgpath);
    // NOT BOTH
endforeach;
```

Then instead of looping through each array index and using `echo`, just use `var_dump()`:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($physpaths);
echo "</pre>";
```

**PROTIP:** You should initialize `$physpaths` as an array prior to your `foreach`.

```
$physpaths = array();

foreach(...):
    .
    .
    .
endforeach;
```

Comment: change ```$physpaths[] = array($imgpath);``` to ```$physpaths[] = $imgpath;``` He wants to echo it later on.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that and changed it.

Comment: Great; might i advise you to mention the reason for initializing the array up front? (Due to php version).

Comment: The reason is that it's good code. You should *never* append data to an uninitialized variable, *especially* an array where you may use it in a `foreach`. If it's left uninitialized, and the creation loop never enters, it's considered `null` and will throw an error. ***Always initialize variables to a default value.***